# ImageMagick memory usage

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have 100 PNG-files and each of them is 8250x4090 big. I need to append them with Imagemagick to one big PNG-file (82500 x 40900) so that I have 10 rows and 10 columns  . I know how the code must look like but I get the errors: convert.exe: unable to extend cache

```
`C:\Row_345.png': No space left on device @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3689.
convert.exe: Memory allocation failed `C:\Row_345.png' @ error/png.c/WriteOnePNGImage/8725.
```

First question: How much space is needed (approximately)? I have 8 GB of Ram and 30 GB free SSD and it wasn't enough. The pictures have polygons and lines in up to 5 different colors. The biggest PNG is 300 KB)
Second question: Is there a way how to make it more clever so that it won't use that much space?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ImageMagick needs 8 bytes per pixel if you are using a Q16 build.  A Q8 build only needs 4 bytes per pixel.

82500 * 40900 * 8 = about 27Gbytes
82500 * 40900 * 4 = about 13.5 Gbytes

The size of the PNG is irrelevant; ImageMagick stores them uncompressed.

Possibly ImageMagick is trying to hold two copies -- your 100 small images plus the large result.  It may be that you'll have enough memory plus disk to run your conversion with ImageMagick-Q8.

Comment: Thanks. I combined your answer with Mark Setchells answer and it worked. but one question: Does Q8 has any downsides like lower quality or something like this?

Comment: As a general rule, Q8 will not be as accurate as Q16.  But for particular operations, including "-append", it should be lossless if your original PNG files have bit_depth==8 or less.

Comment: I must admit that I don't know how to find out the bit_depth of a PNG file. Do you think that this (http://i.imgur.com/Nbm9z8w.png) has a bit_depth of 8?

Comment: You'll be just fine - you only have 4 colours :-) Check it yourself like this `identify -verbose image.png`

Answer (score 10):

Try doing just a single row of 10 at a time, ten times - so you get 10 rows of 10. Then do row1 plus row2. Then rows 1&2 plus row 3.

```
convert 1.png 2.png 3.png ... +append row1.png
convert 11.png 12.png 13.png ... +append row2.png
...
convert 91.png 92.png 93.png ... +append row10.png
```

Then

```
convert row1.png row2.png -append row1and2.png
```

You can add `-debug cache` to your ImageMagick `convert` command like this:

```
convert -debug cache 1.png 2.png 3.png ... +append row1.png
```

You can also look at your resource settings as to what is available to ImageMagick like this:

```
identify -list resource

File         Area       Memory          Map         Disk    Thread         Time
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 768     1.0386GB    3.8692GiB    7.7384GiB    unlimited         4    unlimited
```

And increase resources like this:

```
convert -limit memory 32MiB ...
```

Comment: I also had the Idea with the rows but I still had the same error. I will try -debug cache and -limit memory , thanks!

Comment: So I had to combine yours and Glenn Randers-Pehrsons answers to solve my problem. Which answer do I have to accept?

Comment: Go with Glenn's - I'm sure he'll be pleased to get his 2,000 points!