# Why the real memory usage of ImageMagick is higher than what I expected?

Tags: php, imagemagick

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/26849250

According to the answer above, a Q16 version of ImageMagick needs 8 bytes of memory space per pixel. Now I use Q16 version of ImageMagick, and I have an image (XXX.jpg), which size is 5680 x 3787 (px). Below is my PHP code of ImageMagick:

```
$file = "XXX.jpg";
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage($file);

$type = $image->getImageFormat();
$image->setFormat($type);

echo $image->getImagesBlob();
```

Theoretically, it should take 5680 * 3787 * 8 = 172081280 bytes = about 164.11 MB of memory usage. But I look up the memory usage statistics, the virtual memory usage takes up to 315.03 MB and the physical memory usage takes up to 349.71 MB. The usage amount is extremely higher than what I expected. What happened to the memory usage? Is there any miscalculation?

[image]

By the way, how to calculate the CPU usage of ImageMagick?

P.S. Below is the PHP information of my ImageMagick:

[image]

Comment: Not only the image consumes memory, the code uses memory too.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the total memory usage including the image and the code?

Comment: You're loading and decompressing a jpeg file too. That needs memory as well.

Comment: Q16 ImageMagick needs 16 bytes per pixel ***per channel*** for the input (after decompression) and also similar for the output and for any temporary images created by clones in the command line.

Comment: Why do you want to calculate this ?

Comment: @fmw42 it's 16 **bits** per channel.

Comment: Glenn, thanks for the correction. That was what I wanted to say, but it came out wrong.

Comment: Note that you can get and set resource limits (in terms of RAM, threads, etc) in your code `Imagick::getResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY);`, or in your config files - though that may slow things down if you force it to go to disk.